# How to add select field to FieldArray in formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I follow to this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray } from 'formik';

// Here is an example of a form with an editable list.
// Next to each input are buttons for insert and remove.
// If the list is empty, there is a button to add an item.
export const FriendList = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Friend List</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ friends: ['jared', 'ian', 'brent'] }}
      onSubmit={values =>
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }, 500)
      }
      render={({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray
            name="friends"
            render={arrayHelpers => (
              <div>
                {values.friends && values.friends.length > 0 ? (
                  values.friends.map((friend, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                      <Field name={`friends.${index}`} />
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)} // remove a friend from the list
                      >
                        -
                      </button>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => arrayHelpers.insert(index, '')} // insert an empty string at a position
                      >
                        +
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  ))
                ) : (
                  <button type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push('')}>
                    {/* show this when user has removed all friends from the list */}
                    Add a friend
                  </button>
                )}
                <div>
                  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          />
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
```

But that for text input Field. 
I want to replace to `select` and I do something like that.

Replace:

```
<Field name={`issues.${index}`} />
```

To:

```
<Field component="select" name="color">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Field>
```

I add 3 component when I choose the value in one component, It's effect to all of the component.

What did I wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `name` property for each `select` input needs to be unique. Try the following

```
<Field component="select" name={`friends.${index}`}>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="green">Green</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray } from "formik";

// Here is an example of a form with an editable list.
// Next to each input are buttons for insert and remove.
// If the list is empty, there is a button to add an item.
const FriendList = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Friend List</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ friends: ["jared", "ian", "brent"] }}
      onSubmit={values =>
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }, 500)
      }
      render={({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray
            name="friends"
            render={arrayHelpers => (
              <div>
                {values.friends && values.friends.length > 0 ? (
                  values.friends.map((friend, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                      <Field name={`friends.${index}`} />
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)} // remove a friend from the list
                      >
                        -
                      </button>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => arrayHelpers.insert(index, "")} // insert an empty string at a position
                      >
                        +
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  ))
                ) : (
                  <button type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push("")}>
                    {/* show this when user has removed all friends from the list */}
                    Add a friend
                  </button>
                )}
                <div>
                  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          />
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);

export default FriendList;
```